# Locations Problem on GeoServer

Tags: geoserver

I am using Open Source Geoserver for showing assets locations which are captured/geotagged on the Google Map with Google Map API using javascript and C#  with SQL Server backend. But when this stored information  in SQL Server is retrieved in GeoServer the locations are then shown somewhere else as where these were captured/geotagged.

Comment: which CRS did you set in SQL server and in GeoServer? where should the points be and where do they show up

Comment: I am using SRS  4326 in sql server as well as in Geoserver

Comment: But it is happening in only one form where as other forma/pages are showing locations quite fine at their actual places.

Comment: please add a screen shot of where your points are and a note of where you expect them to be